# Store powershell result in json to Azure storage account

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I need to store the powershell json output into azure storage account using windows powershell ISE. Eg: "$result" is the output file to be stored in storage account

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

Firstly, we can store the PowerShell JSON output in a local file using below command :

```
$result | out-file /path/to/file
```

Then we can copy the file from local to azure storage account using below command :

```
az storage blob upload --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key 0000-0000 --container-name mycontainer --file /path/to/file --name myblob
```

Comment: In case, if I have to do the whole activity in Azure Runbook (powershell) and upload the result directly into Azure storage account how this can be achieved?
Eg: "$result" & "$result1" are the output file to be pushed directly in storage account